# BlocBuilder changes the state, but does not change the text on the screen

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have the following problem:
I made a mini-app on the BLoC architecture.
But I do not change the text on the screen.

I also made similar screens and they worked, maybe I just missed something, but I checked with the official documentation and it seems like everything should work.

Flutter Version-1.22.5

Version of Bloc and Flutter Bloc - 6.1.0

Who can tell you what the problem is?

Here is the app code:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'bloc/hello_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: MyHomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final HelloBloc helloBloc = HelloBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => HelloBloc(),
      child: BlocBuilder<HelloBloc, HelloState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is HelloPrinted) {
          return Center(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text("Hello"),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      helloBloc.add(PrintBloc());
                    },
                    child: Text("Print Bloc"))
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        if (state is BlocPrinted) {
          return Center(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text("Bloc"),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      helloBloc.add(PrintHello());
                    },
                    child: Text("Print hello"))
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text("Start print hello first"),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      helloBloc.add(PrintHello());
                    },
                    child: Text("Print hello"))
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

hello_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'hello_event.dart';
part 'hello_state.dart';

class HelloBloc extends Bloc<HelloEvent, HelloState> {
  HelloBloc() : super(HelloInitial());

  @override
  void onTransition(Transition<HelloEvent, HelloState> transition) {
    print(transition);
    super.onTransition(transition);
  }

  @override
  Stream<HelloState> mapEventToState(
    HelloEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is PrintHello) {
      await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      yield HelloPrinted();
    }
    if (event is PrintBloc) {
      await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      yield BlocPrinted();
    }
  }
}
```

hello_event.dart

```
part of 'hello_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class HelloEvent {}

class PrintHello extends HelloEvent {}

class PrintBloc extends HelloEvent {}
```

hello_state.dart

```
part of 'hello_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class HelloState {}

class HelloInitial extends HelloState {}

class HelloPrinted extends HelloState {}

class BlocPrinted extends HelloState {}
```

Thank you all in advance for your answers.

Comment: I think the problem is if you are providing bloc yourself in blocBuilder you must pass it in parameter. In older version it is `bloc:` in newer ones you must use `cubit:`. ref: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html

Comment: i added cubit, but its not working yet, but thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating two instances of your `HelloBloc`. One that you're using to add your events, and the other within your BlocProvider

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final HelloBloc helloBloc = HelloBloc();
```

```dart
return BlocProvider(
    create: (context) => HelloBloc(),
```

To fix this, remove the instance that you are using to save as a variable (the first one) and to add your events use `context.read<HelloBloc>().add(...)`

This will call on the right instance and will update your UI

Answer (score -1):

you always have to send another state in between to update a state. So if you want to update HelloPrinted you need to send something like yield InProgress() first.

```dart
if (event is PrintHello) {
      yield InProgress();
      await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      yield HelloPrinted();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply!
i'm tried to add state "Inprogress" and add in hello_bloc.dart "yield InProgress();" before delayed, but its still not working.

Even though I can see Transition:

"flutter: Transition { currentState: Instance of 'HelloInitial', event: Instance of 'PrintHello', nextState: Instance of 'InProgress' }
flutter: Transition { currentState: Instance of 'InProgress', event: Instance of 'PrintHello', nextState: Instance of 'HelloPrinted' }"

Comment: if you added InProgress to hello_state.dart, I don't see anything wrong. You should either debug your code or add some print statements in the bloc and the ui file to see where it fails. The big mistake you had was not sending an intermediate state, which would prohibit it you from updating a state.

Comment: I set all exceptions and added "print" before.
But i dont seeing any fails.
The only thing I noticed after changing the state is it doesn't even go to builder and so doesn't change the data on the screen depending on the state

Comment: Change your UI to `builder: (context, state) {print("1"); if (state is HelloPrinted) { print("2"); return Center(` and add 3 and 4 to the other if and the else statement and follow the flow.  What happens?

Comment: Printed 1 and 4, but only first time. After clicked on button, in console printed only Transition without numbers

Comment: You do not need to always yield another state in between states. If you wish to provide a loading state you may do so. The reason that you don't have to do this is because bloc will always send out a state that is not identical to the previous state. If you aren't using equatable correctly, or your values are mutable, then its more than likely that bloc will not reemit your state.

Comment: Then I do not know, what I am doing wrong.  I think to properly use equatable, nevertheless it never works without sending an intermittent state. Could this be a difference when using MapToEvent of flutter_bloc?